# Symbols printed when English alphabet wanted - Vigenere cipher - Python

Tags: python-3.x, vigenere

I am using Python 3.4.1. I am trying to create a Vigenere cipher and I have recently come across this error. Normally, you would hope to have the English alphabet printed, however it is printing symbols. I will post an example of the printed code below.

> > Please insert the message you would like to use: dan
> >     Please insert the keyword you would like to use: can
> >       gb|

please could someone point out where I have gone wrong, I will paste the code below:

```
A = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
C = input("Type in e : ")

if C == "e":

    MM = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
    KK = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")    
    ik = len(KK)
    i = 0
    string = ''

    for A in MM:

        message1 = (ord(A)) - 96
        key1 = (ord(KK[i])) - 96

        addition = message1 + key1 + 96            
        string += (chr(addition))

        if i >= ik:
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1

    print (string)
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. What is your expected output? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: the problem is that symbols are being printed instead of the alphabet

Comment: The code does exactly what it is supposed to do. `ord(n) - 96` is `14`. `14 + 14 + 96` is `124`, exactly what `|` is in ASCII. You do want to think about what you are doing. It looks like a simple ROT-n chiffre, so you need to wrap the scale if you do not want to use all of ASCII.